# how to get name of a month in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Display the month name of date “14-jul-15” in full.

I have tried multiple ways but i am not able to get it to display the name of the month.

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-FC63D86D-EB36-4A19-995E-C3C146747DF4).

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format mask.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'fm dd-Month-yyyy') result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
------------------
 25-March-2021

SQL>
```

---

Or, if all you have is a string `'14-jul-15'`, the first convert it to a valid date value (using `TO_DATE`), and then apply `TO_CHAR` to it.

I'm using then `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` parameter as well because my database speaks Croatian so "jul" is invalid month for me. You might not need it.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '14-jul-15' from dual)
  3  select
  4    to_char(
  5            to_date(col, 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english'),
  6            'fm dd-Month-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english'
  7           ) result
  8  from test;

RESULT
------------------
 14-July-2015

SQL>
```

Comment: You may want to use `'dd-fmMonth-yyyy'` because `to_char(DATE '2021-03-01', 'fm dd-Month-yyyy')` returns `1-March-2021` instead of `01-March-2021`

Comment: Sure, that's an option. Thank you, @Wernfried.